# How many times do we need to use auxiliary verb in a sentence?

Tags: sentence-choice

Which one is correct sentence? I'm asking how many times I need to use 'will' in a sentence?

1. One day I will have so many cars that I will not even remember how many cars I will have.
2. One day I will have so many cars that I don't even remember how many cars I have.

Should I use 'will' again and again?

Comment: A much shorter example: *I will meet you when you arrive* - not *...when you **will** arrive*.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [future or present with when.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/56459/future-or-present-with-when) Where the Answer starts off by explaining why *Give me a call when you **will** get my message* is invalid.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Reinstate Monica...Okay so that means my second sentence is correct.

Comment: @Rocky No, it is not correct. You need to replace **don't** with **won't**. In practice the sentence is likely to read: **One day I will have so many  cars that I won't even remember how many (cars) I have.**